# Modelagem ER "sistema" acadêmico

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, modelagem

Pessoal álguem poderia me ajudar?
Estou fazendo um trabalho de banco de dados no qual tenho que fazer um "sistema" acadêmico,
desenvolvi esse ER da foto, tenho duvidas do tipo: Como faço para o professor armazenar as notas e frequências ?
Como faço para o aluno visualizar essas notas e frequências?
Desde já grato pela Força.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Notas está mais relacionado a disciplina e aluno do que professor. Aluno possui nota em disciplina, logo, nota é um atributo de disciplina vinculado ao id de um aluno e a uma disciplina. Imagino q precisa de uma tabela a parte, já que precisa cruzar informação de aluno e de disciplina.

Comment: Uma relação de N pra N entre aluno e disciplina geraria uma outra tabela,  
 é isso?

Answer (score 0):

Dê uma olhada nesse modelo: [image: academico]

Na entidade associativa, é mostrado um exemplo de como armazenar o histórico do aluno (basta adaptar ao seu). Para o aluno ver, basta montar uma consulta SQL após o seu modelo conceitual for mapeado para o lógico e depois para o modelo físico.